# Can I use a list comprehension to create a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given this value:

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

is there a way to use a list comprehension to produce this value:

`[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]`?

I'd prefer to do it without using zip, if possible.

Thanks!

Edit: My reason for not wanting to use zip was that I used zip to do something similar before (albeit not a list of lists), and it was recommended that I try a list comprehension instead, which made it a little neater. I thought the same principle might apply here, but maybe not, since this is a list of lists and not just a single list like the previous problem.

Also, my attempts at this before posting this question were not even worth sharing. It was basically a list comprehension that created a single list, and I couldn't figure out how to create a list of lists with it. Maybe it's not as simple as I had hoped. I might go with zip after all.

Comment: FYI - this will get downvoted aggressively unless you show what you've tried so far to make this work. It doesn't have to be right, just an attempt.

Comment: Why not use `zip`? It's the fastest, most concise possible way to do this.

Comment: You can still use the comprehension to tweak the tuples, but `zip(*alist)` is the most common idiom for 'transposing' a list of lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```py
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Using `zip` you can take values from inner lists together and using `*` you can unpack these values

```py
[*zip(*list1)]
```

or

```py
list(map(list,zip(*list1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Without `zip`:

```
>>> [*map(lambda *a: [*a], *a)]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without zip:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
output = [[a[0][i],a[1][i],1[2][i]] for i in range(0,len(a))]
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
original = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
result = []
for x in range(len(min(orig))):
    result.append([item[x] for item in orig])
```

Based on my testing, this works just like @Himanshu's method of doing `[*zip(*list1)]` and `list(map(list,zip(*list1)))`